# Recover linear transformation of Covariance Matrix

Tags: covariance-matrix, linear-algebra

Suppose that I can observe $\Sigma_1$ (r x r), and $\Sigma_2$ (r x r)= $A \Sigma_1 A'$, for some arbitrary (r x r) rotation matrix $A$.

Is it possible to recover $A$ in any meaningful way?

Comment: No. Orthogonal matrices are orthogonal. Take $P$ to be another orthogonal matrix. Then $PA\Sigma_1 A’P’ = B\Sigma_1 B’$ where $B=PA$ is also orthogonal. It’s not identifiable

Comment: You can observe both $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$? I.e. you have two datasets?

Comment: Yes. More specifically, the DGP is one such that the variance changes.

Comment: @Daeyoung That's incorrect: diagonalizing the $\Sigma_i$ gives a formula for uniquely recovering $A,$ at least when all their (necessarily common) eigenvalues are distinct. Zeyuz: a change in variance is *not* given *via* conjugation by an orthogonal matrix. Are you sure, then, that you have asked the right question??